# How to compare each element of one array to another if present then print Yes otherwise no

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, sorting

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[8] = { 1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 8, 12, 5 }; 
    int b[6] = { 1, 3, 12, 5, 9, 10 };    
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
        {
            if(b[j]==a[i])
            {
                cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
            }
        }
        cout<<"NO"<<endl;
    }
}
```

i have to compare these array and of element of second array is present in first array then print yes else no 
.
I am getting output as

```
Yes
NO
NO
Yes
NO
NO
NO
NO
Yes
NO
Yes
NO
```

I have to get output like this

```
yes
yes
yes
yes
No
No
```

Comment: Your program is written in C++, not in C. As those are two different languages, please tag your question properly. Also, poor indentation makes it hard to see which statements belong to which loop.

Comment: sir can you please write sudo code. i am new in programming i am not getting you .

Comment: There is no _sudo_ code, it's pseudo code. :)

Answer (score 3):

The primary point to mention here is that, once you've found a match, you need to `break;` out of the inner loop.

Also, you need to make sure to print *either* "yes" or "no". As your program currently stands, it will unconditionally print "no" after the inner loop. You can make use of a flag to accomplish that.

Finally, as your logic states, *"....of element of second array is present in first array"*, you need to change the loop structure to reflect that. The outer loop should be used to index the second array `b` whereas, in the inner loop, you should be traversing the first array `a`.

You need to do something like (*pseudo code, not tested*)

```
for (int j=0; j<6; j++) {
int flag = 0;   //reset the flag

    for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        if(b[j]==a[i])
        {
            cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!flag) cout<<"NO"<<endl;
 }
```

Comment: Plus invert the for loops.

Comment: @O'Neil is that necessary?

Comment: @SouravGhosh it is if they want only six output results and not eight.

Comment: @SouravGhosh As I understand, the purpose is to determine if each element of `b` in witihin `a`.

Comment: Now it should be at par.

Answer (score 2):

Per your stated goal in your question, you should be enumerating your second array (`b[]`) as your outer loop, hunting for each of its values within your first array (`a[]`) as the inner loop, and most importantly, breaking the loop with detection (code outside the inner loop knows you broke early) if you found a match and thus know whether Yes or NO should be printed

In short, your algorithm is backwards and still not complete. Fixing the algorithm and using ranged-for as the enumeration method (use it or use subscripting like you are now, up to you), gives us:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a[8] = { 1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 8, 12, 5 };
    int b[6] = { 1, 3, 12, 5, 9, 10 };

    for (auto x : b)
    {
        bool found = false;
        for (auto y : a)
        {
            if (x == y)
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        std::cout << (found ? "Yes" : "NO") << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
NO
NO
```

Answer (score 2):

The whys of your broken algorithm have been already given by the other answers. I would like to give you a hint that can help to improve it in terms of time of execution (once fixed, of course).

Note that two nested loops means a complexity of *O(N*M)*, where *N* is the length of `a` and *M* is the length of `B`.
For you are working with integers, if you can accept to spend a few bytes of space (*O(N)*) for a set, you can reduce the complexity to *O(N+M)*.
Moreover, the whole code seems to me even easier to understand:

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<unordered_set>

int main() {
    int a[8] = { 1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 8, 12, 5 }; 
    int b[6] = { 1, 3, 12, 5, 9, 10 };

    std::unordered_set<int> check{a, a+8};

    for(int j=0; j<6; j++) {
        if(check.find(b[j]) != check.cend()) {
            std::cout << "Yes" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "NO" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The basic idea is this:

- Iterate over `a` and put all the values in your set
- Iterate over `b` and check if the set contains the _i-th_value

The second step doesn't require anymore to iterate over `a` for each value in `b`. Therefore the overall complexity is reduced (in the average case at least - see the documentation of `std::unordered_set` for further details).

Answer (score 1):

A more C++ way to do it would be to use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) (C++11 inside):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a[8] = { 1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 8, 12, 5 };
    int b[6] = { 1, 3, 12, 5, 9, 10 };

    for (auto bi : b)
    {
        bool found = std::find(std::begin(a), std::end(a), bi) != std::end(a);
        std::cout << (found ? "Yes" : "No") << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did change in your program and it gives the expected output.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        int flag = 0;
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
            if(b[i]==a[j]) // take b array value and compare with all elements of a.
            {
                cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
                flag = b[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (b[i] != flag)
            cout<<"NO"<<endl;            
    }
```